# generate logs based on date using logging application block for EL 5.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, enterprise-library

I am using logging application block for EL 5.0. I defined listener like below.

```
    <add name="FlatFile TraceListener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.
Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"              
listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.
    Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"
        fileName="C:\Temp\RssLog.log" header="--------------"
        footer="----------------------" formatter="Brief Format Text"
                      traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" />
```

How can generate log file daily?. like today=`Rsslog10182011.log` tomorrow = `Rsslog10182011.log`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a rolling flat file trace listener that will give you a file for each day.  This is from EL 4.1 but it is the same for EL5.

```
        <add fileName=".\Logs\exception.log" footer="" formatter="Trace Formatter" header="" rollFileExistsBehavior="Overwrite" rollInterval="Midnight" rollSizeKB="0" timeStampPattern="yyyyMMdd" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" traceOutputOptions="Callstack" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Exception TraceListener"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Rolling Flat File Trace Listener instead.  For example you could try this for starters:

```
<add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" 
     type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     fileName="RssLog.log" 
     rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" 
     rollInterval="Midnight" />
```

You can download the [Enterprise Library 5.0 documentation](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/43135) for more details on configuring the Rolling Flat File Trace Listener.