# How to generate one log file per day

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

How can I use a file per day with EnterpriseLibrary,

I have the following code:

```
    private static void configureLog(string logFile)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

        builder.ConfigureLogging()
               .LogToCategoryNamed("General")
                 .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()
                 .SendTo.FlatFile("Log File")
                   .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder()
                     .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")
                       .UsingTemplate("{message}"))
                     .ToFile(logFile).WithHeader(string.Empty).WithFooter(string.Empty);

        var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
        builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);            
        EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);            
    }
```

But it always generate one log file.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you use configuration over code for this. You can use the rolling flat file trace listener. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812724/generate-logs-based-on-date-using-logging-application-block-for-el-5-0

Comment: sorry, in my project we must use this way, but i changed to use Rolling file and it is generating a new log file per day but it still recording log in the older file.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Quartz.NET to Schedule this Process for Every Day and call the Same .

Comment: I solve this problem, thanks. But now I have other, may you can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767555/wrong-content-rollingfile-log

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using RollingFile configuration:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

    builder.ConfigureLogging()
      .LogToCategoryNamed("General")
      .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()                   
      .SendTo.RollingFile("Log File")
      .RollEvery(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollInterval.Day)
      .UseTimeStampPattern("yyyyMMdd")
      .WhenRollFileExists(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollFileExistsBehavior.Overwrite)
      .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder()
            .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")
            .UsingTemplate("{message}"))
     .ToFile(SettingsHelper.LogFilePath)                         
     .WithHeader(string.Empty)
     .WithFooter(string.Empty);                         

      var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
      builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
      EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```