# Wrong content RollingFile Log

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library

I'm using RollingFile log from Enterprise Library and I'm configuring it by this way:

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

    builder.ConfigureLogging()
      .LogToCategoryNamed("General")
      .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()                   
      .SendTo.RollingFile("Log File")
      .RollEvery(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollInterval.Day)
      .UseTimeStampPattern("yyyyMMdd")
      .WhenRollFileExists(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollFileExistsBehavior.Overwrite)
      .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder()
            .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")
            .UsingTemplate("{message}"))
     .ToFile(SettingsHelper.LogFilePath)                         
     .WithHeader(string.Empty)
     .WithFooter(string.Empty);                         

      var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
      builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
      EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

### My problem is:

The log must be one file per day, ok, it is done.
But when I open the log file of date 04/21/2016 for example, the content is of date 04/20/2016.
Why is this happen? Is something wrong in the configuration?

Comment: Is the time on the server correct?

Comment: @xman I was testing this changing the server time, like, I waited it write some log, then I changed the server time and waited a little bit. The log file was there but its content was wrong.